# Django 1.11 - Password reset

Tags: django, django-1.11

I have an issue with a password modification form.
I don't want to use the password reset function from Django.

```
def view_password(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = ChangePasswordForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                new_password = form.cleaned_data['new_password']
                confirm_password = form.cleaned_data['confirm_password']
                if new_password == confirm_password:
                    strengh = new_password[0].isalpha()
                    if all(c.isalpha() == strengh for c in new_password):
                        messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'Le mot de passe doit contenir au moins 8 charactères lettres et chiffres.')
                    else:
                        update = User.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
                        update.set_password('new_password')
                        update.save()
                        messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'Votre mot de passe a bien été changé.')
                else:
                    messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'La confirmation du mot de passe est incorrect.')
            else:
                messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'Une erreur est survenue pendant la modification.')
        else:
            form = ChangePasswordForm()
        return render(request, 'password.html', locals())
    else:
        from start.views import view_logon
        messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'Vous devez être connecté pour accéder à cette page.')
        return redirect(view_logon)
```

The form works well and the modification of the password is done. However, after looked at the database, it seems that the new password is not well hashed. Indeed when I try to login with the new password or the old password, it doesn't work.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Probably you just need to remove quotes around `new_password`: `update.set_password(new_password)`?:)

Comment: Yeah, thanks for you help :) I need a break I think ^^

Answer (score 0):

Change the line,

```
update.set_password('new_password')
```

To,

```
update.set_password(new_password)
```

You were setting the password as 'new_password' for every users. That's why you can't login.

`set_password` takes the argument as a string and hashes as the password.